# Concurrency issues when retriveing Ids of newly inserted rows with ibatis

Tags: java, postgresql, ibatis

I'm using iBatis/Java and Postgres 8.3.
When I do an insert in ibatis i need the id returned.
I use the following table for describing my question:
`CREATE TABLE sometable ( id serial NOT NULL, somefield VARCHAR(10) );`
The Sequence `sometable_id_seq` gets autogenerated by running the create statement.

At the moment i use the following sql map:

```
<insert id="insertValue" parameterClass="string" >
 INSERT INTO sometable ( somefield ) VALUES ( #value# );
 <selectKey keyProperty="id" resultClass="int">
  SELECT last_value AS id FROM sometable_id_seq
 </selectKey>
</insert>
```

It seems this is the ibatis way of retrieving the newly inserted id. Ibatis first runs a INSERT statement and afterwards it asks the sequence for the last id.
I have doubts that this will work with many concurrent inserts.

Could this cause problems? Like returning the id of the wrong insert?

( See also my related question about [how to get ibatis to use the INSERT .. RETURING .. statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769688/howto-return-ids-on-inserts-with-ibatis-with-returning-keyword) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely wrong. Use:

```
select currval('sometable_id_seq')
```

or better yet:

```
INSERT INTO sometable ( somefield ) VALUES ( #value# ) returning id
```

which will return you inserted id.

Comment: So you think it will cause problems. My other question is about howto get the INSERT INTO .. RETURNING .. statement into ibatis (Since i cant post a link in here i added it at the end of the question)

Comment: Of course it will. try yourself with 2 connections from psql.

as for ibatis - i have no idea what it is, but it looks java-related - which means i can't help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple example:

```
<statement id="addObject"
        parameterClass="test.Object"
        resultClass="int">
        INSERT INTO objects(expression, meta, title,
        usersid)
        VALUES (#expression#, #meta#, #title#, #usersId#)
        RETURNING id
</statement>
```

And in Java code:

```
Integer id = (Integer) executor.queryForObject("addObject", object);
object.setId(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another thought. `ibatis` invokes the  insert method delegate the Class: `com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate,with the code`:

```
 try {
      trans = autoStartTransaction(sessionScope, autoStart, trans);

      SelectKeyStatement selectKeyStatement = null;
      if (ms instanceof InsertStatement) {
        selectKeyStatement = ((InsertStatement) ms).getSelectKeyStatement();
      }

      // Here we get the old value for the key property. We'll want it later if for some reason the
      // insert fails.
      Object oldKeyValue = null;
      String keyProperty = null;
      boolean resetKeyValueOnFailure = false;
      if (selectKeyStatement != null && !selectKeyStatement.isRunAfterSQL()) {
        keyProperty = selectKeyStatement.getKeyProperty();
        oldKeyValue = PROBE.getObject(param, keyProperty);
        generatedKey = executeSelectKey(sessionScope, trans, ms, param);
        resetKeyValueOnFailure = true;
      }

      StatementScope statementScope = beginStatementScope(sessionScope, ms);
      try {
        ms.executeUpdate(statementScope, trans, param);
      }catch (SQLException e){
        // uh-oh, the insert failed, so if we set the reset flag earlier, we'll put the old value
        // back...
        if(resetKeyValueOnFailure) PROBE.setObject(param, keyProperty, oldKeyValue);
        // ...and still throw the exception.
        throw e;
      } finally {
        endStatementScope(statementScope);
      }

      if (selectKeyStatement != null && selectKeyStatement.isRunAfterSQL()) {
        generatedKey = executeSelectKey(sessionScope, trans, ms, param);
      }

      autoCommitTransaction(sessionScope, autoStart);
    } finally {
      autoEndTransaction(sessionScope, autoStart);
    }
```

You can see that the insert and select operator are in a **Transaction**. So I think there is no concureency problem with the insert method.