# Howto return ids on Inserts with Ibatis ( with RETURNING keyword )

Tags: java, postgresql, ibatis

I'm using iBatis/Java and Postgres 8.3.
When I do an insert in ibatis i need the id returned.
I use the following table for describing my question:
`CREATE TABLE sometable ( id serial NOT NULL, somefield VARCHAR(10) );`
The Sequence `sometable_id_seq` gets autogenerated by running the create statement.

At the moment i use the following sql map:

```
<insert id="insertValue" parameterClass="string" >
 INSERT INTO sometable ( somefield ) VALUES ( #value# );
 <selectKey keyProperty="id" resultClass="int">
  SELECT last_value AS id FROM sometable_id_seq
 </selectKey>
</insert>
```

It seems this is the ibatis way of retrieving the newly inserted id. Ibatis first runs a INSERT statement and afterwards it asks the sequence for the last id.
I have doubts that this will work with many concurrent inserts. ( [discussed in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769595/concurrency-issues-when-retriveing-ids-of-newly-inserted-rows-with-ibatis) )

I'd like to use the following statement with ibatis:
`INSERT INTO sometable ( somefield ) VALUES ( #value# ) RETURNING id;`

But when i try to use it within a `<insert>` sqlMap ibatis does not return the id. It seems to need the `<selectKey>` tag.

So here comes the question:

How can i use the above statement with ibatis?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `<selectKey>` element is a child of the `<insert>` element and its content is executed *before* the main `INSERT` statement. You can use two approaches.

**Fetch the key after you have inserted the record**

This approach works depending on your driver. Threading can be a problem with this.

**Fetching the key before inserting the record**

This approach avoids threading problems but is more work. Example:

```
<insert id="insert">
  <selectKey keyProperty="myId"
             resultClass="int">
    SELECT nextVal('my_id_seq')
  </selectKey>
  INSERT INTO my
    (myId, foo, bar)
  VALUES
    (#myId#, #foo#, #bar#)
</insert>
```

On the Java side you can then do

```
Integer insertedId = (Integer) sqlMap.insert("insert", params)
```

This should give you the key selected from the `my_id_seq` sequence.

Comment: this solution resolves my concurrency worries. It only leaves the question if ibatis can work with a INSERT INTO .. RETURING .. syntax.

Answer (score 10):

Here is simple example:

```
<statement id="addObject"
        parameterClass="test.Object"
        resultClass="int">
        INSERT INTO objects(expression, meta, title,
        usersid)
        VALUES (#expression#, #meta#, #title#, #usersId#)
        RETURNING id
</statement>
```

And in Java code:

```
Integer id = (Integer) executor.queryForObject("addObject", object);
object.setId(id);
```

This way more better than use :

1. It's simpler;
2. It have not requested to know sequence name (what usually hidden from postgresql developers).

Comment: That would be the answer I was searching for...
but it is not working: when using executer.queryForObject the id is returned, but nothing is inserted, and when i use executer.insert the row is inserted, but null is returned

Comment: That very strange, because I copy&paste my work code. 
Also I don't understand - how can you get id without adding new record?

What do you see in iBatis SQL log?

Comment: Sounds like one of you has auto-commit enabled, and the other doesn't.