# Java iBatis Missing INTO Keyword

Tags: java, oracle11g, ibatis

I'm receiving this error when I run my iBatis insert command:

```
DEBUG [main] - Returned connection 31746664 to pool.
DEBUG [main] - Checked out connection 31746664 from pool.
DEBUG [main] - {conn-100014} Connection
DEBUG [main] - {conn-100014} Preparing Statement:          INSERT INTO PORTFOLIOS              ( theme_id             , start_date             , portfolio_name             , amount             , index_cd             , model_cd             , last_rebalance             , months_between_rebalance             )         VALUES             ( 1             , SYSDATE             , ?             , ?             , ?             , ?             , SYSDATE             , ?)         RETURNING portfolio_id     
DEBUG [main] - {pstm-100015} Executing Statement:          INSERT INTO PORTFOLIOS              ( theme_id             , start_date             , portfolio_name             , amount             , index_cd             , model_cd             , last_rebalance             , months_between_rebalance             )         VALUES             ( 1             , SYSDATE             , ?             , ?             , ?             , ?             , SYSDATE             , ?)         RETURNING portfolio_id     
DEBUG [main] - {pstm-100015} Parameters: [testPortfolio2New, 100000.0, null, null, 0]
DEBUG [main] - {pstm-100015} Types: [java.lang.String, java.lang.Double, null, null, java.lang.Integer]
com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:   
--- The error occurred in ObjectRelationalMapping.xml.  
--- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.  
--- Check the sectoranalysis.domain.insertPortfolio-InlineParameterMap.  
--- Check the statement (update failed).  
--- Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00925: missing INTO keyword
```

The relevant bits in my mapping file are:

```
     <insert id="insertPortfolio" parameterClass="com.fimt.sectoranalysis.domain.portfolio.Portfolio">
        INSERT INTO PORTFOLIOS 
            ( theme_id
            , start_date
            , portfolio_name
            , amount
            , index_cd
            , model_cd
            , last_rebalance
            , months_between_rebalance
            )
        VALUES
            ( 1
            , SYSDATE
            , #name#
            , #investment#
            , #index.ticker#
            , #model.modelId#
            , SYSDATE
            , #frequency#)
        RETURNING portfolio_id
    </insert>
```

I don't understand because the INTO keyword is quite clearly there. Why is my Oracle DB returning this error?

Answer (score 1):

The syntaxt is:

```
INSERT INTO (...) VALUES (...) RETURNING (...) INTO (...)
```

In your example Oracle is complaining because it expects the second INTO keyword.
I would try using statement with resultClass parameter:

```
<statement id="insertPortfolio" parameterClass="com.fimt.sectoranalysis.domain.portfolio.Portfolio" resultClass="int">
... 
</statement>
```

For some more examples please see:
[Howto return ids on Inserts with Ibatis ( with RETURNING keyword )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769688/howto-return-ids-on-inserts-with-ibatis-with-returning-keyword)