# Issue returning id with Postgres 8.4

Tags: java, postgresql, ibatis

I am trying to do an insert for return generated id INSERT RETURNING id. In postgres editor it work without problems, but in code execution - java 1.6 with iBatis 3 (8.4 postgres driver version 8.4-702) gives the error - Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near " RETURNING. "
It this means Postgres does not support Returning to insert?

I found this online - [Concurrency issues when retriveing Ids of newly inserted rows with ibatis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769595/concurrency-issues-when-retriveing-ids-of-newly-inserted-rows-with-ibatis)

but not how to do

Code iBatis xml

```
<insert id="insertNewItem" parameterType="itemAlias" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="item_id">
    INSERT INTO items (
        category_id,
        description,
        ...)
    VALUES(
        #{category_id},
        #{description},
        ...)    
    RETURNING item_id
</insert>
```

Comment: The insert itself looks correct to me. Did you try to run that without using iBatis (e.g. in psql)? I guess iBatis is messing with the statement somehow...

Comment: -1 For bilingual content

Answer (score 1):

**La respuesta es:**

```
Public void insert(Item itemAlias) {
SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
try {
Session.getMapper(ItemMapper.class).insert(itemAlias);
Logger.debug("itemAlias id:" + itemAlias.getItem_id());  // Here this you give you the generated key.
}
Finally {
Session.close();
}}
```

MyBatis xml

```
<insert id="insertNewItem" parameterType="itemAlias" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="item_id">
INSERT INTO items (
    category_id,
    description,
    ...)
VALUES(
    #{category_id},
    #{description},
    ...)
</insert>
```

*MyBatis guys helped me. Thanks a lot*

Answer (score 0):

i htink u miss some concept here. RETURNING is neither RETURN nor SELECT. it just throw  some variable out. To make it work, the statement gonna look like this

```
declare tmp integer;

INSERT INTO items (
        category_id,
        description,
        ...)
    VALUES(
        #{category_id},
        #{description},
        ...)    
    RETURNING item_id INTO tmp

return tmp;
```

u can change integer to your primary key data type